# How to get api result before open activity (waiting screen)

Tags: android, performance, api

I had two activities in the first time, the first one and the Main one that opens allow the user to choose a parameter (student informations) from a list then send it in a SharedPreferences to the second Activity.
The second activity takes the parameter that the user selected then put call an API that returns the result concerning the student and display it.
The problem is when the second activity starts, it takes a while, and displays in a first time the blank components.
It looks like the activity is bugging and doesn't make it easy for the user.

I actually want to add an Activity as a middle one to display the waiting message, and execute the api call in the background then go to the activity where I'm supposed to get the result.
I tried sharedPreferences but it's not really working better.

Comment: You could place a ProgressBar on either of those activities.

Comment: I added it in the middle Activity (waiting one) but how I would execute the api call from this one? if i do I must get the result then send them in SharedPreferences to the third one.

Comment: You shouldn't need a middle activity, you need to place the ProgressBar on the activity that makes the api call, while it is making it.

Comment: @LeoPelozo The activity that's making the call is the second one.
Main Activity --> SendParameter
Details Activity --> GetParameter then call the API.

Comment: On second activity hide all views and display an [indeterminate progress bar](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/attachments/pb1-png.70077/) while making the call, then you can display the retrieved data.

Comment: @LeoPelozo it's just taking two times longer seconds